# Hibernate Bytecode Instrumentation: Set fetched property values to their fields right away

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm working on an enterprise application that uses Hibernate and EJB, and I'm utilizing Hibernate's Bytecode instrumentation to implement true lazy-loading of properties having bidirectional `@OneToOne` associations. I have a service method implemented using EJB, and as we all know, EJB uses RMI, which uses native Java serialization and deserialization to facilitate RPC invocations. The service method returns an entity with needed properties already fetched using JPQL, but since Hibernate doesn't set the fetched properties eagerly to their target fields, clients calling the service method end up receiving entities with properties having `null` values. Aside from calling the property getters manually before returning the entity, is there a way to tell Hibernate to set fetched property values automatically to their corresponding fields?

I'm using Hibernate 5.3.15 and JBoss EAP 7.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, EJB doesn't necessarily use RMI, I guess what you mean is EJB remoting. There is no way that I know of to force field initialization except for initializing the fields through some means (access). One way to overcome this is to use DTOs that simply do not do any lazy initialization.

I think that this might be a bug in the serialization code of Hibernate for such bytecode enhanced proxies, so please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

If you want to take the DTO approach, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    UserDetailsDto getDetails();

    @EntityView(UserDetails.class)
    interface UserDetailsDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getFirstname();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!